# How to use .XCompose to produce snippets?

Tags: 18.04, compose-key

**OS**: Kubuntu 18.04 or Ubuntu 18.04

According to an answer in [vi.stackexchange.com](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2256) and [this GitHub page](https://github.com/Carpetsmoker/dotfiles/blob/master/x11/XCompose) including

```
<Multi_key> <i> <b> : "NL65AEGO0721647952"
```

in `~/.XCompose` should generate `NL65AEGO0721647952`. But I can't get that to work. Nothing happens in plain text editors in Ubuntu or in Kubuntu.

I checked `/usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose` to see if `<Multi_key> <i> <b>` was used for anything else but it isn't.

My `~/.XCompose`

```
include "%L"

<Multi_key> <i> <b> : "NL65AEGO0721647952"
```

I have <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> as my Compose Key and can type other stuff like ©, ™, ®, µ, etc.

**Edit**:
Even

```
# Make compose key work for GTK, Qt
export GTK_IM_MODULE=xim
export QT_IM_MODULE=xim
```

doesn't help.

Comment: [A comment](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2254/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-insert-unicode-characters-into-a-document/2256#comment1968_2256) says it doesn't work for KDE.

Comment: But I can't get it to work in Ubuntu as well.

Comment: @muru And the comment you linked is from someone who's been battling, for years, to get KDE/qt to use `Ctrl+Shift+u` followed by Unicode the way gtk uses it. I don't think it's related to using the Compose key, which, by and large, works in KDE.

Comment: I see. Anyway, if I run gedit in the terminal, with `<Multi_key> <a> <b> : "askj" foobar` in my `.XCompose`, I get this error: `(gedit:4944): Gtk-WARNING **: 13:45:20.035: GTK+ supports to output one char only: "askj" foobar: <Multi_key> <a> <b> : "askj" foobar` .... Looks like it no longer works with GTK.

Comment: @muru, right now I'm back on Kubuntu but I have leafpad (gtk2) and mousepad (gtk3) text editors installed. Both work with the snippet only if launched via the terminal and not when launched by keyboard shortcuts! Geany, also gtk3, produces a message similar to what you see.

Comment: I made it work in Ubuntu; please see [this bug comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ibus/+bug/1845332/comments/2).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a bug report [1845332](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ibus/+bug/1845332) about this at launchpad.
<s>Could you please mark it also affects you?</s>

**Upd:** There is a response for this bug report.

**How to make Compose key combination generate strings** (Ubuntu 18.04):

- Open `Settings → Region & Language → Manage installed languages → (Language tab)`
- Switch `Keyboard input method system` to `XIM`.
- Close.
- Reload.

It supposed to work also for distributions based on Ubuntu.

If XIM is working better, why it is not default?

**Explanation**:
(see answer for original [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ibus/+bug/1845332))

For keyboard input Ubuntu can use [XIM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Input_Method) (X Input Method) or [IBus](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBus) (Intelligent Input Bus) or none.

XIM is very old, it was designed for X (X Window System). If/when Ubuntu switches from X to Wayland it will be most likely dropped.

The default keyboard input method now (18.04) is IBus, because Ubuntu uses GNOME for GUI and GNOME relies on IBus to a large extent.
When IBus is selected for keyboard input method, GTK (not IBus) deals with Compose key combinations. GTK is not able to handle multi character strings. So it is not an IBus bug, it is GTK feature. No fix is expected here.

From the other side, XIM can make problems too, and most likely they will not be repaired either.

So far XIM works for me. I wonder what will happen with this issue if XIM will pass away.